# Is it possible to check if an user is authorized to edit another user without using a try catch statement?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, access-rights

I am writing A script in PowerShell that fills basic information in Active Directory Such as: Phone #, Office location, Manager, nickname, and Job Title. This is used to populate user information in office 365 and is used for our university's phone directory. Sometimes the program is able to successfully modify information and sometimes it cannot.

FOR EXAMPLE

User1: successfully able to edit information

User2: successfully able to edit information

User3: successfully able to edit information

User4: not able to edit information

User5: successfully able to edit information

My program can edit users 1,2,3, and 5 because I have the security clearance to do so. I cannot change user 4 because that user has an higher security clearance. My solution currently is to wrap A `Set-ADuser` around A try catch statement like so To catch that problem.

```
if($user_main.Office -ne $person.'Work Contact  Work Mail Stop')
{
    try
    {
        Write-Host Office location was changed to $person.'Work Contact  Work Mail Stop'
        Set-ADUser $user_main -Office $person.'Work Contact  Work Mail Stop'
        $writer.WriteLine("$timestamp`t$display`t$action`t$outcome`tadd or edit to Office location")
    }
    catch [System.ServiceModel.FaultException]
    {
        $writer.WriteLine("$timestamp`t$display`t$action`t0`tunauthorized add or edit to Office location")
    }
}
```

Is there A way for me to Check if I Have the correct security rights to edit information about users such as user 4 so I do not have to use the try-catch method?

Comment: If the account has rights to "Read Permissions" on the User Object. So you could check the ACL. E.g. `(Get-ACL 'AD:\CN=Example,CN=Users,DC=Example,DC=com').Access` But this is going to be be a pain as the rights are going to be delegated by group. 

The [PowerShellAccessControl Module](https://github.com/PowerShellOrg/PowerShellAccessControl) has a `Get-EffectiveAccess` command would make that easier.